# Does being Level 5 Blacksmith make sense in Normal mode?

Tags: diablo-iii

I managed to get to the last upgrade of level 4 in blacksmith in the end of act I by using the party money to upgrade only one character. From now, I need these blacksmith pages to upgrade, and they can only be obtained in Nightmare mode (or on act IV, whatever).

I craft items that are already useful or will soon be useful, i.e., level requirement on items is not my worry now.

The bad thing is that now it's gonna be a little hassle to get those pages before Nightmare, so I want to know, is it viable to upgrade? More specifically: do all items made in level 5 require high level (~ 35+), or more important, do they take more stuff to prepare that I do not have access now, on act II?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each difficulty level has it's own crafting materials. For example, in Nightmare Mode, [Subtle Essence](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/item/subtle-essence) is replaced by [Shimmering Essence](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/item/shimmering-essence), and [Fallen Teeth](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/item/fallen-tooth) is replaced by [Lizard Eyes](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/item/lizard-eye).

Once you start needing drops from a higher difficulty to train your smith in higher levels, you can know that you won't be able to craft anything learned at those higher levels without materials from those higher difficulties.

So, in short, **No**, there's no real benefit to doing this. You can also [browse all of the crafting recipes, sorted by Smithing level over at Blizzards Game Guide site.](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/artisan/blacksmith/recipe/) As you can see, Level 5 Crafted items learned via training require level 30 or above, [at which point, you should be in Nightmare mode.](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/66707/what-level-is-recommended-before-starting-nightmare-hell-inferno) If you're learning these recipes while you're still in Normal Mode Act II, you're either *severely* overleveled, or you're *already* at a point where you can craft things long before you're able to use them.

Answer (score 4):

Right now, the best way to upgrade your characters is through the Auction House. Prices are rock bottom on Rares, with many good upgrades available at buyouts around 1000 gold.

Undoubtedly, there will be some great things the blacksmith can craft at the highest levels, but it might be more prudent to wait until then to start upgrading him further. Presumably, you'll be into Nightmare mode, and gradually collecting the pages of training.

Even then, you may find it easier to buy the fruits of others labor on the Auction House so you can get exactly the stat combinations you want. Gold will get easier and easier to come by as you go up in difficulty.

So to answer your question more thoroughly, do not spend the money to get those pages of training early from the AH. Go ahead and upgrade through itemization, and get the pages naturally through playing the game. By the time you reach the highest levels, you should be good to go.