# Do Corrupt Vessels turning into Thralls give more loot and XP?

Tags: diablo-iii

Corrupt Vessels are much easier to kill before they become Tormented Thralls. They don't move, they don't attack and they have less health. The Thralls are harder to kill because they move, hit and have more health.

But, do the Thralls compensate for it by giving more experience and loot?

[image: Screenshot of Tormented Thrall] [image: Screenshot of Corrupt Vessel]

Comment: Great question... I don't know the answer.

Comment: I doubt you will actually get more XP, as you give up on the Massacre bonus.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Regarding XP:

Corrupt Vessel:

- Normal : 120
- Nightmare : 460
- Hell : 1300
- Inferno: 1600

Tormented Thrall:

- Normal : 120
- Nightmare : 460
- Hell : 1300
- Inferno: 1600

### Regarding loot:

The thrall is of the same level as the vessel, so they have identical drop rates. Do keep in mind, however, that Tormented Thralls have a higher chance (75%) of dropping Health Globes than Corrupt Vessels (5%).

Source (Diablo III Brady Games Guide):

> If a monster drops loot, the quality of the item(s) dropped is most affected by the monster's level. If the loot bursts from an environmental object like a chest or barrel or pile of bones, the type/quality of items is most affected by where you're at in the game.
>
> Other factors can come into play, as well. The fact is, Diablo III monsters can drop a wide range of loot items, but the odds of a low-level monster dropping a high-quality item are extremely small. So overall, it works just as you'd expect: The higher a monster's level, the better chance that it drops good loot after you slay the beast.

Comment: Please add info regarding the loot.

Comment: The guide does not give Loot information

Tormented Thralls do however have a higher chance (75%) of dropping Health Globes than Corrupt Vessels (5%)

Corrupt Vessels do more damage than Corrupt Thralls, but Corrupt Thralls have more life.  I can't post actual pictures showing all the stats, I'm sure it would be violating some kind of copyright :)

Comment: Please add it to the answer.

Answer (score 2):

No, you will not receive any bonus EXP or loot. All standard mobs have the same drop rates too.

Comment: do you have any sources to back this up?

Comment: All enemies share the same random item drop rate. If they are champions/rares/bosses, obviously they have a higher drop rate. This is from experience, and Diablo's (1/2/3) loot logic.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know the droprate only differs by act and wether you kill champion packs/bosses or normal mobs. But all normal mobs have the same dropchance for items, so the Tormented Thralls do not have a higher droprate for better items.

Since bigger enemies most times give more XP you could wait until they transform, but you should be able to kill more of the Corrupt Vessels in less time so that the XP is not worth fighting those charging thralls, especially not in Inferno difficulty, they can be a pain in the a** ;-)

Comment: do you have any sources to back this up?

Comment: Inferno doesn't really matter for XP, as its really unlikely you will get there before level 60.

Comment: @Alok On top of that, I believe you have to actually be level 60 to play in Inferno.  See http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/66709/16953

Comment: @Troyen: I forgot that part, but I can confirm it - had to run around in Hell at lvl 59 :(